# Passing command line input in Groovy script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am writing a Jenkins pipeline using Groovy. My requirement is to connect to a remote machine using ssh. How can i pass the password for the remote Linux machine in the groovy script. I am using below to invoke ssh command:

```
def proc = 'ssh username@ip address'.execute()
```

My question is can i pass password in the same line..or is there any another way for it.

Thanks,
Shalini

Comment: if you are in pipeline then why you are not using ssh steps: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-steps/  ?

Comment: Hi Shalini - any reason not to use ssh keys?  That avoids the problem with ssh prompting for a password.

Comment: Do not use Groovy's `execute()` method. This will be executed on the Jenkins Master only and is not how pipelines work. Use either the `sh` step to call shell commands or - as suggested by @daggett, a more specialized step (see [steps reference](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/)).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you All, i was able to get my problem resolved using ssh steps .